# ¿Cómo evito que el frame se ajuste al contenido, dejarlo de un tamaño fijo?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy intentado usar un `Frame` de Tkinter usando `Grid` como *geometry manager*, pero este se ajusta al contenido, aunque tenga un tamaño definido.

El código que tengo es este:

```
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk
Ventana=tk.Tk()
Ventana.title("Calculo de Raices metodo Secante")
Ventana.configure(bg="#424949")
Ventana.geometry('1000x800')

frmBotones = tk.Frame(Ventana,bg="#7F8C8D",height=100,width=100,padx=5,pady=5)
frmBotones.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

frmGrafica = tk.Frame(Ventana,bg="#D6DBDF",height=500,width=500)
frmGrafica.grid(row=2, column=1)

frmTabla = tk.Frame(Ventana,bg="#4D5656",height=500,width=500)
frmTabla.grid(row=2, column=2)


# Estos botones van dentro del frame pero el frame se ajusta a los botones
# y quiero dejarlo de un tamaño fijo:

Helvfont = font.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, weight="bold")
tk.Button(frmBotones,text="graficar",font=Helvfont,fg="blue").grid(row=1,column=3)
tk.Button(frmBotones,text="Hola",font=Helvfont,fg="blue").grid(row=1,column=2)

Ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola @LeonelGalicia, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Comment: Hola podrias ayudarme?

Comment: Realmente no podría ayudarte, ya que no tengo conocimientos de python. Pero aunque los tuviera, con la información que nos das nos es muy difícil. Me remito a mi comentario de arriba. Revisa la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Debes añadir un ejemplo [Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder trabajar sobre algo y ayudarte a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Leonel bienvenido a [es.so]. Agrega el código como te indica zeross. ¿Con "frame python" te refieres a Tkinter supongo? ¿Qué geometry manager usas (`pack,`, `grid`, etc) ¿cómo se relaciona con el resto de los widget y con su widget raíz? Si agregas el código y explicas que esperas conseguir exactamente podremos ayudarte. Para agregar el código usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163268/frame-sin-ajuste-automatico) que hay debajo de la pregunta, lo copias y lo pegas, luego lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor para formatearlo. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla replanteare la pregunta, uso geometry grid, esperare ayuda de verdad la necesito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por defecto  el *[`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) manager* que maneja el `Frame` intenta adaptar el tamaño de éste a su contenido de forma automática y redimensionarlo cada vez que un widget secundario cambia de tamaño. Este es normalmente el  comportamiento esperado.

Puedes desactivar esta característica mediante el método [`grid_propagate`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method) del widget:

```
frmBotones.grid_propagate(False)
```

Con lo que el `Frame` quedará con un tamaño de 100 x 100 pixeles sin importar lo que contenga.

Por supuesto, esto implica que vas a tener que ajustar manualmente el tamaño de los botones que contiene.

[`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) tiene un método idéntico, [`pack_propagate`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_propagate-method), no así [`place`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) ya que en este caso podemos definir la posición/tamaño (absoluto o relativo) de cada widget de forma explícita.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla me servira de mucho, es un proyecto de Universidad. Le pido un consejo ¿Cúal geometry manager me recomienda `grid`, `pack` o `place`?

Comment: @LeonelGalicia eso depende de que quieras hacer y como quieras que los widgets se adapten a la ventana o widget padre en cuanto a tamaño y posición. `pack` te permite apilar widgets en una sola fila o una sola columna, `grid` te permite organizar los widgets en forma de tabla y `place` te permite dar la posición y tamaño de un widgets de forma explícita (coordenadas) pudiendo ser el tamaño y la posición absolutas o relativas a las de otro widget. Ten en cuenta que se pueden combinar en una misma app siempre que no se aplique en un mismo widget padre ) y es común hacerlo en una GUI "compleja".

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla, tomare en cuenta su respuesta. Gracias por la amabilidad. Exitos diarios siempre.

Comment: @FJSevilla , a mí me está pasando algo parecido pero con widget Text de Tkinter. La cosa es que el Text tiene un **width** y **height** establecidos y un font, por ejemplo, `font=('Consolas', 12)`, pero si cambio el tamaño de la fuente, bien reduciéndolo o aumentándolo, también, se cambia el tamaño del Text de la misma forma. He aplicado el `grid_propagate(False)` al Text pero no se soluciona. El Text está dentro de un Frame con tamaño fijo y que tiene también el `grid_propagate(False)`. ¿Alguna forma de que, al cambiar el tamaño de fuente del Text, no afecte al tamaño del propio elemento?

Comment: La respuesta a lo que planteo en mi comentario anterior de "¿Alguna forma de que, al cambiar el tamaño de fuente del Text, no afecte al tamaño del propio elemento?" en esta otra pregunta: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167602/qué-hacer-para-que-el-tamaño-de-fuente-influya-en-el-tamaño-del-text)