# ¿Qué hacer para que el tamaño de fuente no influya en el tamaño del Text?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un Text con unas determinadas propiedades de anchura, altura, fuente, ...
El Text está dentro de un Frame.
La cuestión que he observado es que si cambio el tamaño de la fuente a aplicar al contenido del Text, no solo cambia el tamaño del contenido textual sino que, también, cambia el tamaño del propio elemento Text.

Es decir, por defecto, el `Text` tiene `font=('Consolas', 11)` y todo cuadra, perfectamente, en cuánto a los tamaños de la ventana, Frame y Text.
Pero, si disminuyo o aumento el tamaño de la fuente, disminuye o aumenta, igualmente, el tamaño del widget Text.

Este es el código de ejemplo:

```
# encoding: utf-8


from Tkinter import *

import os


class MiTkinter(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        frame_txt = Frame(self, bg='grey')
        frame_txt.pack()
        frame_txt.config(padx=10, pady=10)
        frame_txt.config(width=295, height=345)
        frame_txt.grid_propagate(False)

        # Valor(es) Predeterminado(s)
        self.bg_color = 'black'
        self.fg_color = 'white'

        self.text_origin = Text(frame_txt, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
        self.text_origin.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.text_origin.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=('Consolas', 11), selectbackground='lightblue', width=24, height=16, bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)
        #self.text_origin.grid_propagate(False)

        text_origin_contenido = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'''
        self.text_origin.insert(1.0, text_origin_contenido)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
    os.system('clear')

    # Tk (Raíz) objeto raíz por defecto
    # ==========================================================
    root = MiTkinter()

    root.title('Probando ~ Tamaño de Text')
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(295, 345, 400, 100))

    root.mainloop()
```

¿Habría alguna opción o configuración del Text para que el tamaño de éste no se viera influido por el cambio del tamaño de la fuente?
Vi en [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163268/c%C3%B3mo-evito-que-el-frame-se-ajuste-al-contenido-dejarlo-de-un-tama%C3%B1o-fijo/163332), referente en ese caso a un Frame, que se podía aplicar el método de `.grid_propagate(False)`.
He probado esto con el Text, pero, sin efecto alguno.

¿Alguna otra solución para esto? Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ancho de un `Text` se define según número de caracteres en lugar de píxeles, esto es lógico ya que hay que mostrar siempre caracteres completos. Por otro lado intenta usar el ancho asignado como su ancho mínimo siempre que sea posible, estableciendo `N` caracteres como su ancho en función de la fuente y tamaño inicial. La consecuencia es que intenta siempre mantener *N* caracteres de ancho, por lo que si se asigna una fuente mas ancha el widget se ensancha y viceversa.

Para tener un `Text` de tamaño fijo la idea general es la siguiente:

- Meter el `Text` en un `Frame` propio.
- Hacer que este `Frame` contenedor  no se vea forzado a ajustar su tamaño para adaptarse al del `Text` que contiene. Esto lo consigues con `grid_propagate(False)`. Hay que tener en cuenta que esto evita que el `Frame` se adapte a sus hijos, no evita que su hijo (el `Text`) cambie de tamaño.
- Forzar al `Text` a ocupar todo el espacio disponible de su `Frame` contenedor, esto se puede hacer de diferentes formas, vía `pack(fill="both", expand=True)`, con `grid` configurando la columna y fila que contienen el `Text` con `weight = 1`...

Un ejemplo con dos `Text` basado en el código de la propia pregunta:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

######## Python 3 ###########
#import tkinter as tk
#import tkinter.font as tkFont



class MiTkinter(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='grey', padx=10, pady=10, width=600, height=345, relief="sunken")
        self.parent_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self._text1_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=10)
        self._text2_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=10)

        frame_text1 = tk.Frame(self.parent_frame, width=300, height=345, relief="sunken")
        frame_text2 = tk.Frame(self.parent_frame, width=300, height=345, relief="sunken")
        frame_text1.pack_propagate(False)
        frame_text2.pack_propagate(False)
        frame_text1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        frame_text2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.bg_color = 'black'
        self.fg_color = 'white'

        self.text1 = tk.Text(frame_text1,
                             wrap='word',
                             bd=0,
                             padx=6,
                             pady=4,
                             font=self._text1_font,
                             selectbackground='lightblue',
                             width=24,
                             height=16,
                             bg=self.bg_color,
                             fg=self.fg_color,
                             insertbackground=self.fg_color,
                             highlightbackground=self.bg_color,
                             highlightcolor=self.fg_color
                             )

        self.text2 = tk.Text(frame_text2,
                             wrap='word',
                             bd=0,
                             padx=6,
                             pady=4,
                             font=self._text2_font,
                             selectbackground='lightblue',
                             width=24,
                             height=16,
                             bg=self.bg_color,
                             fg=self.fg_color,
                             insertbackground=self.fg_color,
                             highlightbackground=self.bg_color,
                             highlightcolor=self.fg_color
                             )

        self.text1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        text = ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,'
                'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n\n'
                'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
                'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,'
                'sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.')

        self.text1.insert(1.0, text)
        self.text2.insert(1.0, text)

        btns_frame1 = tk.Frame(self.parent_frame, bg='cyan', padx=5, pady=5, width=295, height=45)
        btns_frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btns_frame1.pack_propagate(False)

        tk.Button(btns_frame1, text="-", font=("Courier", 20), command=lambda: self.decr_font(self._text1_font)).pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="y")
        tk.Button(btns_frame1, text="+", font=("Courier", 20), command=lambda: self.incr_font(self._text1_font)).pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="y")


        btns_frame2 = tk.Frame(self.parent_frame, bg='cyan', padx=5, pady=5, width=295, height=45)
        btns_frame2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        btns_frame2.pack_propagate(False)

        tk.Button(btns_frame2, text="-", font=("Courier", 20), command=lambda: self.decr_font(self._text2_font)).pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="y")
        tk.Button(btns_frame2, text="+", font=("Courier", 20), command=lambda: self.incr_font(self._text2_font)).pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="y")

    def incr_font(self, font):
        font.config(size=font["size"] + 1)

    def decr_font(self, font):
        font.config(size=font["size"] - 1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MiTkinter()
    root.title('Probando ~ Tamaño de Text')
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(660, 430, 400, 100))
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡¡Muy Bien, maestro!! Solo, cuando ví tu respuesta en la otra pregunta que referencio, creía que cuando añades un elemento con `pack()` a éste le correspondía el `pack_propagate(False)` y si lo añades con `grid()` pues, entonces, había que usar `grid_propagate(False)` ... Ahora que, tu, en tu código, haces una combinación ya que le asignas a los `frame_text1` y `frame_text2` el `pack_propagate(False)` aunque los añades por medio de `grid()`. Lo que me ha resultado confuso o, aunque sea, curioso. Pero bueno, no tocar lo que funciona como tiene que funcionar.